# `sequence` seems to work incorrectly with `Either`

Tags: haskell

When I use `sequence` on `Maybe`, everything seems to work fine:

```
sequence [Just 2, Just 3] == Just [2, 3]
sequence [Just 2, Just 3, Nothing] == Nothing
```

The result type is as per the `sequence` type: `(Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)`, the `m (t a)` becomes `Maybe [Int]` and it is correct for `Nothing` too.

However, if I do something like this:

```
sequence [Right 2, Right 3] == Right [2, 3]
sequence [Right 2, Right 3, Left 4] == Left 4
```

How is `Left 4` of type `m (t a)`? If `Right [2, 3]` is `Either [Int]` then `Left 4` should also by of that type, but obviously (to me) it isn't. What am I missing?

Comment: `Left` is like `Nothing` for a `Maybe`.

Comment: Yeah but it's not nullary, it takes an argument and this argument has to have a type, the same type `Right` takes, as far as I understand.

Comment: `m` is here `Either b`, not `Either`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let is first do the type analysis. The `m` is *not* `Either`, the `m` is `m ~ Either b`. Indeed, since `m` takes a *single* type parameter.

So if we set `m ~ Either b`, then we get:

```
(Traversable t) => t (Either b a) -> Either b (t a)
```

and with `t ~ []`, we thus get:

```
[Either b a] -> Either b [a]
```

You can see `Either b` as a more sophisticated version of `Maybe` where `Left e` is used to show an error (computation that failed) with `e` the error object (this can for example be a string, or some other type), and `Right x`, a computation that succeeded with `x` the result. In that case `sequence` will thus check if the list of computations succeeded, and if it did it will return a `Right [x1, x2, …, xn]`, and if one of the computations failed, it will return the *first* "error object".

This is based on the instance of `Monad (Either b)`, [indeed [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Data.Either.html#line-155):

> ```
> -- | @since 4.4.0.0
> instance Monad (Either e) where
>     Left  l >>= _ = Left l
>     Right r >>= k = k r
> ```

For a `Left l`, it will thus return a `Left l`, whereas for a `Right`, it will apply `k` to the result `r`.